# split on words except when phrase contains that word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

I am trying to split where clauses, I want to split text on `AND|OR|NOT` except when `NOT` is in the 'phrase' `NOT IN` or `NOT LIKE` or `IS NOT NULL`.

1st example:

```
DEVLDATE IS NOT NULL AND STATUS = D AND PICKUPDATE IS NULL
```

I expect 3 segments, splitting on the `AND`'s, but not on the `NOT` in this instance.

2nd ex:

```
(NOT (STATUS IN ('A','X') )) AND LINEHAUL = 0
```

I want to split on this `NOT` & `AND`, also expecting 3 segments in this instance

I'm trying this look ahead from another almost similar example but it is not splitting at all.  I have next to zero regex experience.  Not sure what I'm missing or if it's even possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
var ignoreRegex = /(?!.*\b([NOT IN]|[NOT LIKE]|[NOT BETWEEN]|[IS NOT NULL])\b)(?=.*\b(AND|OR|NOT)\b)/g
var filterArray = filterBy.split(new RegExp(ignoreRegex));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
\b(AND|OR|NOT(?!\s+NULL|IN|LIKE))\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hQ9gU8/2)

About your regex:

```
(?!.*\b([NOT IN]|[NOT LIKE]|[NOT BETWEEN]|[IS NOT NULL])\b)(?=.*\b(AND|OR|NOT)\b
```

- `[NOT IN]` - this is character class `[...]` it will match character
  which you put in in, so it can match: N,T,etc. not whole
  word/sentence,
- `([NOT IN]|[NOT LIKE]|[NOT BETWEEN]|[IS NOT NULL])` - this whole part actually can match only one character, because it doesn't use any quantifires or intervals, it doesn't work as you expect at all,
- so whole regex should match: some text with AND, OR or NOT, but if line within which the part was matched doesn't consist letters and spaces included in character classes..... so it will not match anything probably.

Comment: Beat me by a second...I'd recommend `\s+`, though, because `NOTNULL` could be a false positive. Also, OP, feel free to add back in your `\b` word boundaries.

Comment: @Sam never ending SO answer race :D and you are right, thank you for hint!

Comment: @m.cekiera   thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  and also thank you for the explanation.